# ActiveRecord: how to reference two FK of the same class

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a table with `primary_address_id` and `delivery_address_id` columns referencing rows in a table containing street addresses. I would like to create model with ActiveRecord so I could write

```rb
ci = Contact.create(full_name: 'Willy', company: 'Chocolate Factory')
pa = ci.primary_address.create(street: 'Seestrasse', city: 'Kilchberg')
da = ci.delivery_address.create(street: 'Flughafenstrasse', city: 'Zurich')
```

(Basically I would like to achieve functionality similar to [an example on RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark).)

contact.rb:

```rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :primary_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  belongs_to :delivery_address, :class_name => 'Address'
end
```

address.rb:

```rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I try to run `ci.primary_address.create` from above example I get:

```
...activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing': undefined method `create' for #<Address:0x007f8ef9132128> (NoMethodError)
    from /.../main.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

---

I would like to know whether does my model make any sense and why create method is unavailable?

I am using ActiveRecord outside of Rails.

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE contacts
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    company VARCHAR(20),
    primary_address_id INT(11),
    delivery_address_id INT(11),
    CONSTRAINT primary_address_fk FOREIGN KEY (primary_address_id) REFERENCES addresses (id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT delivery_address_fk FOREIGN KEY (delivery_address_id) REFERENCES addresses (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE addresses
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street VARCHAR(40),
    city VARCHAR(20),
);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what your code looks like becasue it is actually calling `create_other` which is not a method on `Address` so I am assuming something is missing here.

Comment: @engineersmnky you are right, I tinkered with code and posted another error message. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that in the example to which you refer, the relationship between the two models is the other way around.  Your contact record belongs_to your address record, whilst in the example the relationship is has_many.

has_many (or its close friend has_one) is probably a more natural way to express the relationship here - unless you are intending to attach one address record to many contact records.

Just checked the rails documentation - has_many gives you a create() method; belongs_to does not.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I have used belongs_to because it places FKs referencing addresses in `contacts` table what seems natural to me. How would you model this relation with has_many?

Comment: I don't think I would use has_many.  The natural way to express it would seem to be `has_one primary_address` and `has_one delivery_address`. Then use `Address.create()` and assign them.

Comment: So you would put these has_ones to `Contact` class and foreign keys to `addresses` table?
Thanks for `Address.create` hint. It seems to be working with my original schema and unmodified `Contact` class.